# Legal page says user content is under cc-by-sa-3.0, but other pages say cc-by-sa-2.5

Tags: bug, status-completed, legal, creative-commons

The [legal page](https://stackoverflow.com/legal) has two references to "the Creative [Commons Attribution Share Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license," and both of them link to [cc-by-sa version 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

However, the bottom of every page links to [version 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).  So does [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/creative-commons-data-dump-aug-10/).

EDIT: There are some noteworthy differences between the two.  3.0 has a no endorsements clause, and it introduces the concept of a "[Creative Commons Compatible License](http://creativecommons.org/compatiblelicenses)", a third-party license approved by CC as "essentially equivalent" (none are approved yet).  The generic license was renamed to be the [US license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/), and they made a new "[unported](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)" license (linked above) to fulfill a similar role.  3.0 is also approved as free [by Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/DFSGLicenses#CreativeCommonsAttributionShare-Alike.28CC-BY-SA.29v3.0).  CC has a [article](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Version_3) and [blog entry](http://creativecommons.org/weblog/entry/7249) with more info.

Comment: Good catch, not sure what the differences are between 2.5 and 3.0. Summary looks the same.

Comment: So, uh, here's a thing. The edited legal page says "the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license"  with no version. It happens to link to the version 2.5 license, but does not explicitly say so. This creates ambiguity.

Comment: @matt the link is explicit and this should suffice

Comment: @Jeff — you're the one with the legal team, so I'll take your word for it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch, I updated it to refer to 2.5 for consistency if nothing else. Not sure if the minor tweaks of 3.0 over 2.5 are particularly relevant to us, or not.

edit: as of yesterday, we re-licensed under cc-by-sa-3.0.

Comment: There's an important way in which they are relevant: content with newer versions of the license isn't backwards-compatible and so cannot be incorporated into stack exchange questions or answers. I know we want new, original content, but sometimes it's helpful to be able to incorporate other CC-licensed material.

Comment: @matt we just re-licensed under 3.0

Comment: outstanding issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214633