# Should Stack Exchange switch to CC BY-SA 3.0?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-exchange, licensing, creative-commons

Currently, Stack Exchange sites use the CC BY-SA 2.5 license.

There's a lot of content (not the least of which is Wikipedia) under the newer 3.0 version of this license.

Content licensed under 2.5 is forward-compatible and can be used with the 3.0 license, but the reverse isn't true -- CC BY-SA 3.0 content can't be used here.

Is there a particular reason SE doesn't use the newer version of the license? Should it be changed?

Comment: What are the difference between the two versions?

Comment: I read the quick summary page for both 2.5 and 3.0 and they are exactly the same.

Comment: @JJNguy http://creativecommons.org/weblog/entry/7249

Comment: @Pekka, ah.  Thanks.  I still have no idea what that means though...

Comment: @JJnguy I can't say I do, either. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61875/legal-page-says-user-content-is-under-cc-by-sa-3-0-but-other-pages-say-cc-by-sa

Comment: As I understand it, the intent is the same, and there are cleanups to the legalese plus the small technical changes listed on the page Pekka links to.

Comment: Wow. I forgot that this whole thing was my fault.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333678/was-the-retroactive-change-to-cc-by-sa-4-0-approved-by-stack-exchanges-lawyers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333388/what-is-the-status-of-the-secure-electronic-opt-out-of-the-mandatory-arbitration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of around April 8, we re-licensed under 3.0:

> There are some noteworthy differences between the two.  3.0 has a no endorsements clause, and it introduces the concept of a "[Creative Commons Compatible License](http://creativecommons.org/compatiblelicenses)", a third-party license approved by CC as "essentially equivalent" (none are approved yet).  The generic license was renamed to be the [US license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/), and they made a new "[unported](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)" license (linked above) to fulfill a similar role.  3.0 is also approved as free [by Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/DFSGLicenses#CreativeCommonsAttributionShare-Alike.28CC-BY-SA.29v3.0).  CC has a [article](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Version_3) and [blog entry](http://creativecommons.org/weblog/entry/7249) with more info.

<strike>[Legal page says user content is under cc-by-sa-3.0, but other pages say cc-by-sa-2.5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61875/legal-page-says-user-content-is-under-cc-by-sa-3-0-but-other-pages-say-cc-by-sa/61919#61919)</strike>  (fixed)

Comment: Ehm, are you allowed to just relicense everyone's content?

Comment: My content was not relicensed, you just purport it was. It's a false statement on your part.