# What is the status of the secure electronic opt-out of the mandatory arbitration that was promised?

Tags: support, security, terms-of-service

In the comments of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer), Tim Post responds to my request for a "secure, electronic means" of the opt-out of mandatory arbitration with the following

> @jhpratt And you'll get one. And a lot of other people in this community wanted an update on this yesterday that included a means that was more convenient, such as email. I can't pretend to be able to please everyone in one fell swoop. A more secure means is coming, you're welcome to wait until then. I would have loved to wait until that was done, but I would have made quite a few people very sad and angry

This comment was made on May 10, 2018. As of this post, it has been 16 months since that comment was made. Multiple people have pinged Tim Post since this initial comment, including myself *multiple times*, most recently three days ago.

I have still not opted out due to Stack Exchange's failure to uphold its promise. I did not use the email method, as I know for a fact that is not secure, and as far as I'm aware, there was never a public key that we could encrypt the message to (and sign it ourselves). I'm not a lawyer, but I suspect the clause would have difficulty holding up in court due to this failed promise.

## Where is our secure out-out of mandatory, binding arbitration that was promised?

All we need is a profile switch. What is taking so long?

Edit: A number of people are mentioning I could have emailed them. Yes, but that's not the point. I have been waiting 16 months for a promised solution that has yet to be released.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use the snail mail method?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I certainly could, but that's not really the point here.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Spending money so that a random internet website can't sue you? Nah.

Comment: To opt out of the user agreement, don’t use the site. :p

Comment: @CrisLuengo All I'm asking is for the ability to opt-out of _a specific part_ that Stack Exchange has said we are able to do. They have not provided the means they promised 16 months ago.

Comment: Technically... You could email a request too. Hardly secure I guess but entirely free

Comment: There are many more features that were "promised" and in the end not delivered. At best we just learned that Tim Post doesn't get to set priorities of the development team and rightfully so.

Comment: You had other avenues of doing so, and didn't take them, even given they aren't secure. As far as "in court" goes, there is a solid argument that you actually didn't want to opt out at all, and now you can't anyway (it's either been more than 30 days or the clauses weren't binding in your jurisdiction anyway). So what exactly is the point of making a new question about this?

Comment: @Nij, there is also a solid argument that the 30-day clock hasn't started yet, or is invalid, even in jurisdictions that permit it: SE promised an electronic opt-out during the snail-mail opt-out period but failed to deliver.  Anyone who relied on that promise has clearly suffered harm, and the obvious remedy is to permit them to opt out even though the opt-out period has expired.