# The mobile version of the website does not show the license along with the contributions

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, licensing, creative-commons

The contributors license their work with a [creative commons license](https://creativecommons.org/use-remix/cc-licenses/) and more specifically "cc by-[sa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share-alike)". This means that the if anybody, e.g. SE, wants to use the work of a contributor then they need to provide the (original) license with the works (or at least one that is not restricting the previous, but that is [another issue](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48824/how-should-copies-of-contributions-from-stackexchange-be-attributed)).

- Full site footer:

  On the regular website this is done by making notice of this license with **a link at the bottom of the page**.

  [image: full site footer]
- Mobile footer:

  However, it seems to me that the version of **the website for mobile phones does not include this link** at the bottom, and any notice of  the license is difficult to find (if any such notice exists).
  [image: mobile footer]

This seems to be to save space on the small screens, but is it reasonable and correct?

Comment: Another reason to quickly abolish the mobile views. In the responsive site it is visible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this oversight to our attention. The license declaration is now included on the mobile site.

Comment: Very nice. One additional point of attention. It is still a bit short and it is not so clear what the license applies to. Currently it might seem like the *entire* mobile website is now cc by-sa and not just the works from contributors.

Comment: Also (the old story), while you are making these edits you could mention that lots of works here are not cc by-sa 4.0 but 3.0 or lower instead. The current notice makes it appear as if the individual works are all  licensed under 4.0 terms but they are not. This is a breach of the terms with the license that you got from your contributors.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus good point. how about "user contributions under cc-by-sa 4.0"? As to 3.0/4.0, we are trying to get that addressed. It's complicated. But not going to be able to solve the issue in the mobile footer at this time.

Comment: Personally, I am happy enough with a commitment to solve the issue with the many works that have a different license version than 4.0 and are currently not correctly attributed with the single attribution in the bottom (although it is missing a time frame, but hearing about the commitment makes me really happy for the moment). This should be turned into a different post/request/bug but I leave it up to others to do it correctly.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus To be pedantic: it's actually 2.5/3.0/4.0.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog to be pedantic about the pedantic remark. I did not exclude the '2.5', and mentioned "or lower". But since I do not know the full history of this website and under which versions contributions have been licensed here before I did not make it explicit (that is not up to me).

Comment: The text of the mobile license in the footer has been changed to "user contributions under cc by-sa 4.0"