# Are there any guidelines for changes of this magnitude?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-exchange-team

By now most people are aware that the value of question upvotes was changed, and millions of reputation points were retroactively awarded. For the purposes of this question let's ignore any debates about whether this was a positive change or a negative change. The fact remains that in the blink of an eye a huge overhaul was applied to the system. People's reputations have drastically changed, and the standing of many users on their particular sites has been upheaved.

My question is pretty straightforward: If this could happen today, what could happen tomorrow?

As far as I can tell, no process was published explaining the details of how this change was decided. No vote was taken. No one was asked if it should be done (I think the moderators were *told* in advance, but I don't think they were *asked*.)

If this is the case, is it possible that tomorrow someone will decide that answer upvotes should only be worth five points, and immediately recalculate everyone's reputation? Or perhaps even answers should be worth no points? Or perhaps reputation should be discarded altogether?

The point is that the precedent this decision sets is staggering. Is there anything ensuring that only certain types of changes will be made? Do we know that we will be able to wake up the next morning and still recognize the site?

This post is not intended as any kind of conspiracy theory, or fear-mongering, or even criticism. I am simply curious if there are any safeguards in place that would prevent enormous changes from being made against the will of the community, or if this issue has been discussed at all.

Can I contribute to the site today and feel confident that everything won't be summarily reevaluated tomorrow?

Comment: This question seems uselessly vague. In the literal senses: odds are good nothing is going to change tomorrow, November 14th/15th, 2019; answers will probably never be worth no points as long as points exist; etc.. For any future tomorrow, for any future change that you deem reevaluation of everything? No.

Comment: Realistically you can't. The calculus has fundamentally changed. At one point, changes were worked through with Meta. That has been in steady decline since Jeff left, to the point where Meta is irrelevant to the company.  Their actions dictate that they have no interest in interacting on meta at a strategic level, and we now must deal with that.

Comment: @Ry- A couple of weeks ago you might have said the same thing...

Comment: I am fairly confident that SE would largely refrain from taking any action that would adversely affect your reputation. Simply because that would cause a huge uproar (even more than that caused by Monica/CoC-gate). This change only increases reputation across the network.

Comment: @Alex: Which same thing? (It’s going to be either “no, I wouldn’t have” or “yes, and it remains true”.)

Comment: @Ry- Your comment about things not changing.

Comment: @Alex: What, “answers will probably never be worth no points as long as points exist”? Yes, I would have said that a couple of weeks ago. I’m also saying it now…

Comment: Why do you think this is such a staggering precedent?  They've removed the rep penalty for downvoting questions, added rep (and later taken away, sort of?) for SO documentation, added various types of comment and question title filtering, and so forth.  Not everything Jeff did was fully discussed (though a much higher % was), and many times his ultimate solution wasn't the one the community wanted.  And it's still early, but "the community" seems [closer to a 40/60 split](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/) compared to say the full negative from removing hot MSO posts from SO.

Comment: @Ry- What would you have said about question value changing?

Comment: @Alex: Nothing ruling out this change? “I hope they make downvotes worth ‒10” is something I’ve said for longer, [also pretty controversial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365526/making-downvotes-more-useful).

Comment: @Troyen Because this change is *retroactive*. If they announce tomorrow that answers will no longer earn reputation I can choose to stop posting answers. But I can’t choose to undo the 1,000+ answers I’ve already posted on the assumption of earning reputation for them.

Comment: This isn't the first time they've retroactively changed reputation.  Iirc, they did the same thing when you were suddenly able to keep rep from deleted posts if the posts were older than 60 days.  In the past decade or so, we've had several major recalcs from system changes.  I doubt this one will be the last.

Comment: @Troyen If I was around for those I might have posted the same thing. Though this one does seem by far to be the largest scale, and affects a more fundamental aspect of the site.

Comment: @Ry- I think you might be missing my point. My point is that someone today saying that it is unlikely that X will be unilaterally retroactively changed is not very comforting because most people probably would have said the same thing about this change as well.

Comment: @Alex: Have you taken a poll? Anyway, that brings me back to “this question seems uselessly vague”. You’re asking if anything surprising is going to happen in the future. Somewhere between maybe and very probably depending on your threshold for surprise?

Comment: As the needs of the site change, the mechanics of the site will also change.  There _was_ a recent discussion that perhaps SO should do away with the reputation system altogether.  That would fix a number of issues, cause a bunch of new ones, and be far more controversial.  Nothing is stopping them from adjusting the site to fit their target audience (whether they are successful at doing so or not).

Comment: @Ry- That's not what I'm asking.

Comment: "in the blink of an eye a huge overhaul was applied to the system": only from your perspective. It took a lot of work by SE, and moderators received earlier notice of the change.

Comment: No, there are no such guidelines. The company will change whatever it wants based on whatever data it wants to, whether that be individual polling, click/view stats, tweets, or any other medium of obtaining or making data.

Comment: Nothing is forever. Don't contribute for the points. Contribute because you want to know something or know something and want to share it.

Comment: @Raedwald I noted in the question that moderators were given advance notice.

Answer (score 13):

> Can I contribute to the site today and feel confident that everything won't be summarily reevaluated tomorrow?

Nope.  You can't even feel confident that the content license you gave won't be [arbitrarily converted to different terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333678/287315).

There might be a guideline to try to minimize bugs or odd hiccups in user experience, but such things [should still be expected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339045/287315).