# The create-chatroom page incorrectly specifies the conversations as licensed under "cc-wiki" (CC BY-SA 2.5)

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, licensing

The [create a new chat-room page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) likely doesn't get a lot of traffic, which probably makes issues with it have a relatively low impact, but this one should be fixed:

> [image]

The text reads:

> All conversations here are public, and they are logged and licensed under the same [cc-wiki](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) license as The Stack Exchange Network.

and yes, that is a link to the CC BY-SA 2.5 "cc-wiki" license that SE moved away from [relatively recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74867/should-stack-exchange-switch-to-cc-by-sa-3-0) (a.k.a. nine years ago). 
<s>Setting aside the questionable status of the [recent shift to CC BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089), there's no sense in having this bit of outdated documentation around and unfixed.</s>
As part of the recent, [much saner approach to license indication for new and old content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344491/an-update-on-creative-commons-licensing), how's about y'all fix this page so that it doesn't create further legal problems?

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for the under-review indication. I find it's a pretty strong indictment of how badly Meta is working if even something this obvious fails to find itself onto a suitable bug-tracking review process without sustained pressure, but hopefully the reworked processes (with which I'm appreciative of the transparency since Theresa Dietrich's recent round of Meta posts) will make it possible to get attention focused onto these things without needing to shout ourselves hoarse.

Comment: Just to understand what track this is on -- will this be rolled into the same consideration package as the rest of the communications about licensing, or is it being considered separately?

Comment: At the moment, no idea. I'm not directly involved in the licensing work, so I'll have to ask around to see what the right approach is here.

Comment: We have a working document of all the nooks and corners that need attention, and I’m adding this to that. It’s where we’re hashing out the rest of the plan to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The license link on the create chat room page is now properly linked.