# Footer and "Legal" pages (still) link to different versions of the Creative Commons license

Tags: bug, status-completed, legal

Redux of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61875/legal-page-says-user-content-is-under-cc-by-sa-3-0-but-other-pages-say-cc-by-sa).

The footer is linking to [version 3 of the license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) but section 3 (User Content) of [the terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) is linking to version 2.5 of the license.

Assuming 3.0 is correct, it is correct in section 2 (Network Content).

Answer (score 1):

The former Section 3 (User Content) is now [Section 6 (Content etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) of the SE Terms of Service page. Section 6 links to [version 4.0 by-sa](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) of the Creative Commons license, see last paragraph of that section.

Section 2 (Network Content) is now a separate page, [Network Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy). The footer reads as follows, and includes a link to CC version 4.0 by-sa:

```
site design / logo © 2019 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions
licensed under cc by-sa 4.0 with attribution required. rev
2019.9.6.34826
```

The Network Content, User Content, and footers of all "legal" pages now link to the same version of the Creative Commons license, CC by-sa/4.0

---

Question should be marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but only site moderators can, as I was informed when I tried to do so just now.

Comment: Are you a Stack Exchange employee? If so, it looks like you lack the "staff" bit, which should allow you to change the tags even without moderator permissions.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog No I am not an SE employee.  That is what I erroneously implied in my answer by stating, "only site moderators can, as I was informed when I tried to do so just now".  Regardless, no action has been taken here, yet it should be.

Comment: Generally, a moderator intervention flag asking for the tag to be added will be honored.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks, I just did that.

Comment: Note that status-completed is the wrong tag, since this change has led to **the wrong licence** being displayed alongside all content older than three weeks (and newer than whenever 2.5 was dropped in a similar fashion).

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Yes, I found that to be true subsequently. I left a comment on your most recent blog post about this and related matters.