# Does SE need to switch to CC-BY-SA 4.0?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, licensing, creative-commons

User contributions to Stack Exchange sites are licensed under Creative Commons; share alike, with attribution required. The version is 3.0, see [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) in the footer.

However, the most current release of Creative Commons was announced a few weeks ago, in November 2013. Version 4.0 is now available, and [all are urged to use it](https://twitter.com/drmaltman/status/405500758805999616). What are Stack Exchange's intentions regarding transition from version 3.0 to version 4.0?

---

This question is not the same as those regarding CC version number inconsistency, e.g. [Footer and "Legal" pages (still) link to different versions of the Creative Commons license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207602/footer-and-legal-pages-still-link-to-different-versions-of-the-creative-comm)  and [Legal page says user content is under cc-by-sa-3.0, but other pages say cc-by-sa-2.5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61875/legal-page-says-user-content-is-under-cc-by-sa-3-0-but-other-pages-say-cc-by-sa).

Comment: See [Commons Coordinations & Copyright Choices 4.0](http://gondwanaland.com/mlog/2013/12/09/scc-cc-40/) for more information about CC 4.0 versus prior CC licenses. It mentions four relevant concerns for us: License proliferation rate (CC 1.0: 17 months, 2.0: 12 months; 2.5: 20 months; 3.0: 81 months); interoperability with existing CC licenses; "domain" coverage e.g. code, data, hardware, other content; differences between 4.0 and prior versions. It may address variations in international jurisdiction applicability, but, well, more about that later, if anyone is still interested.

Answer (score 7):

You are free to use CC-BY-SA 3.0 in CC-BY-SA 4.0 work. <sup>[1]</sup> In other words:

- you can use SE content in your own 4.0 work
- SE can change the license to 4.0 at will

However, you cannot use 4.0 content in a 3.0 work. In other words, until SE updates the license, you cannot paste 4.0 content into a question/answer.

So, for your own reuse purposes, SE does not need to update the license. For SE reuse purposes, SE does need to update the license, [just like they when updated from 2.5 to 3.0.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95033/144115)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> This has been true since CC-BY-SA 2.0:

> Version 2.0 licenses that feature the Share Alike requirement now clarify that derivatives may be re-published under one of three types of licenses: (1) the exact same license as the original work; (2) a later version of the same license as the original work; (3) an iCommons license that contains the same license elements as the original work (e.g. BY-SA-NC, as defined in Section 1 of each license). The version 1.0 licenses required that derivative be published under the exact same license only. Our tweak means much better compatibility across future jurisdiction-specific licenses and, going forward, across versions. Less forking, more fun. (See Section 4b.)
>
> (from "Share Alike Across Borders" in [Announcing (and explaining) our new 2.0 licenses](https://creativecommons.org/weblog/entry/4216))

Alternatively, follow the "More info" link that appears in the "same license" tooltip on the [CC-BY-SA 3.0 human readable license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238997

Comment: SE can not change the license to 4.0 at will. The copyright owner can change the license to 4.0 at will. SE is not the copyright owner. **(Your rep just became 666... )**

Answer (score 7):

### Stackoverflow should move to 4.0 because it is compatible with GPL

One advantage of the CC-BY-SA license 4.0 is that it is compatible with the GPL 3.0 license, which is a license for code.

Using code under the CC-BY-3.0 license in any larger code project is impossible, because CC-BY-SA-3.0 is not recommended for larger code projects, but no code-license is compatible with CC-BY-3.0

## Some code on stackoverflow might be copyrighted

Smaller code fragments are not copyrighted, but some answers contain larger functions which are a grey area.
Currently, we cannot use those functions under the CC-BY license in any code project, even if we are free to choose the license of our project (because CC-BY3.0 is not for larger code projects).
Thus we have to work through the solution to make sure it is indeed a straight-forward way to achieve the goal and thus not copyrighted. Then we are **not bound by the attribution clause** any more, which is bad for stackoverflow.