# Why does Stack Exchange not dual-license content under FDL?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, licensing

Doing my own reading and reasoning about releasing technical content <sup>[1]</sup> under a free license, I have discovered there are these general approaches:

- CC-BY-SA only (e.g. StackExchange)
- [FDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Free_Documentation_License) only (e.g. Free Software Directory) <sup>[2]</sup>
- both CC-BY-SA & FDL (e.g. Wikipedia)

Choosing one of the "only" streets means your work can only be used in similarly licensed works. Choose the "&" option means your work can be used in any of the three.

Has SE explained why they picked CC-BY-SA only, rather than dual-licensing? (This is a question, not a challenge or a suggestion.)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Including software manuals, but not code <sup>[3]</sup>, but including cooking and golfing and maths and stuff cause that's all technical right? :D

<sup>[2]</sup> The *Free Documentation License* is a copyleft content license like CC-BY-SA, but older (conceived at the same time as the more famous GPL license for code). Unfortunately you can't freely copy content between FDL and CC-BY-SA works, so the current solution (if you want to make that possible) is to dual-license. (There is a more elaborate backstory <sup>[4]</sup> here, and as far as I understand the authors of both licenses would like to see a day when they are compatible, it's just not currently possible.)

<sup>[3]</sup> The inevitable code snippet licensing question, which I finally found [an official SE position on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25957).

<sup>[4]</sup> There appear to be fan clubs in fiercely in favour of particular approaches, and opposed to others. I hope this question doesn't trigger those sorts of responses, I really just want to know why SE chose not to take the dual-licensing route. A suggestion to change would be a separate post.

Comment: Speaking as someone who was heavily involved in Wikipedia's licensing, the implementation requirements in the Gnu FDL are a royal pain for any printed work smaller than a software manual.  For example, a one-page printout of a GFDL question and answer would require adding six pages of license statement at the end.  The only reason Wikipedia is dual-licensed is because it's older than Creative Commons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments from @Mark and some further reading, it seems that the Wikipedia dual license is an accident of history,<sup>[1]</sup> not a typical "dual license" and not a common practice.

So, it appears that Stack Exchange simply picked the most popular copyleft content license at the time (CC-BY-SA 2.5, since [updated to 3.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74867),<sup>[2]</sup> and [beyond (?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214549)).

If future versions of BY-SA and FDL are declared compatible,<sup>[3]</sup> dual licensing will not be required [thanks to existing mechanisms in BY-SA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238997), and at that point BY-SA and FDL text would be interoperable.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Possibly inaccurate summary: Wikipedia was created before CC licenses existed so used FDL 1.2 "or later", then switched to BY-SA via a legal mechanism introduced explicitly for this purpose in FDL 1.3. As part of this changeover, Wikipedia no longer accepts FDL input, only PD and BY-SA, and only pages with no BY-SA content are still available under FDL. (see ["Reusing Wikipedia content"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reusing_Wikipedia_content))

<sup>[2]</sup> And [fixed the footers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61875/legal-page-says-user-content-is-under-cc-by-sa-3-0-but-other-pages-say-cc-by-sa/61919#61919) but [not the legal page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214633) (yet)

<sup>[3]</sup> Possibly by the introduction of "FDLv2" and "Simplified FDL v2", which would allow a path for FDL "with no invariant sections" content to avoid the current incompatibilities with CC-BY-SA. I haven't found [anything dated later than 2006](http://gplv3.fsf.org/doclic-dd1-guide.html) regarding this approach, though.